# Could not parse mapping document from resource Select.hbm.xml

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i loading the object from the database,but i got the following exception,please some help me i tired to find the error in my hibernate application,

**Exception**

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException:
>   Could not parse mapping document from resource Select.hbm.xml
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:569)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1587)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1555)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1534)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1508)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
>       at com.java4s.select.SelectMain.main(SelectMain.java:12)
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: 
>       class com.java4s.select.Select.java not found while looking for property: sno
>       at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:74)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.setTypeUsingReflection(SimpleValue.java:276)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindSimpleId(HbmBinder.java:401)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:334)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:273)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:144)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:669)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:504)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:566)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.java4s.select.Select.java
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100) 
>   at
>   org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:70)
>       ... 14 more

**Select.java**

```
public class Select {
private int sno;
private String uname;
private String pass;

public int getSno() {
    return sno;
}
public void setSno(int sno) {
    this.sno = sno;
}
public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}
public void setUname(String pass) {
    this.pass =pass;
}
public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}
public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass =pass;
}


}
```

**SelectMain.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class SelectMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
cfg.configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session=factory.openSession();
Object o=session.load(Select.class,new Integer(1));
Select s=(Select) o;
System.out.println(s.getUname());
}
}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>    
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>    
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2dll.auto">update</property>    
<mapping resource="Select.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>    
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Select.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">        
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.java4s.select.Select.java" table="product1">   
<id name="sno" column="sno"/>    
<property name="uname" column="uname"/>    
<property name="pass" column="pass"/>    
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Did you tried to add the `catalog` property in the hbm file? 
<class catalog="world" name="com.java4s.select.Select.java" table="product1">

Comment: @Atropo i new able to hibernate i don't why need to use catlog property.These are my code i am working,i could not my bug..

Comment: @Atropo no luck,using catlog also not work..

Comment: Post the complete Select.java class

Comment: @Atropo i post my complete Select.java class

Answer (score 1):

You should mape the resource in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` with the full path (of the package):

```
<mapping resource="com/java4s/select/Select.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```

Also check that the `hbm` file is in the same package as the `java` class file.

EDIT:
You have a problem with the mapping of the `sno` property. Check that [hibernate mapping documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration).
I guess you should assign a generator to your `id` field, like for example:

```
 <id column="sno" name="sno">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
 </id>
```

Comment: the previous problem will resolve,but i got new probelm,i upgrade my exception please look at the post..

Answer (score 0):

In Select.hbm.xml file
class name="com.java4s.select.Select.java" table="product1"
change  this line as given below
class name="com.java4s.select.Select" table="product1"

You should give only the class name. .java not required.

Answer (score 0):

Change class name on Select.hbm.xml file
`<class name="com.java4s.select.Select.java" table="product1">` to 
`<class name="com.java4s.select.Select" table="product1">`